# Partial derivative of $h(x,y) = f(y,x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-derivative

$f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and I want to find the partial derivatives of $g(x,y)=f(y,x)$

---

$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y) = \lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{g((x,y)+t(1,0))-g(x,y)}{t} = \lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{g(x+t,y)-g(x,y)}{t}= \lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{f(y,x+t)-f(y,x)}{t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(y,x)$

I understand this, but isn’t the point of finding the partial derivative of $g$ finding it in terms of $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Your calculation is correct.  Your "isn't the point" question has answer, NO.

Comment: If you're geometrically inclined, you can interpret $g(x,y)$ as a composition of functions — first reflect the $xy$-plane across the line $y=x$, then apply $f$. So motion in the $x$-direction turns first into motion in the $y$-direction, and then we see what $f$ does.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry, I don't see this, can you elaborate or maybe explain it in another way? My problem is that I thought that the exercise was meant to show what happens to the partial derivatives of g(x,y) in function of f(x,y) not f(y,x)

Comment: I think you don't understand the notation for a function. Try a concrete example, like $f(x,y) = e^x\sin y$. Now we consider $g(x,y)=e^y\sin x$. What are its partial derivatives?

Comment: $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y) = e^y cos(x)$, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y) = e^y sin(x)$ $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y) =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(y,x) $ $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y) =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(y,x)$